# How to show $1 \otimes x = 0 \in A \otimes B$ implies $x=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $A, B$ be $R$ algebras. 
In particular, $B$ is a field. 
Consider the tensor product $A \otimes_R B$. I have proved that 
the pure tensor $1 \otimes x = 0$. I think it must be the case that then $x=0 \in B$.. but I was not sure how to prove it. Any explanation is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit. $R \to A$ is an injection

Edit 2. The above is false as pointed out in the comments. 
The exact situation I have is the following: 
Let $R \to A$ an injection and $B = R_{P}$, where $R_P$ is $R$ localised at $P$ and $P$ is a minimal ideal of $R$, which makes $R_{P}$ a field.

Comment: This is false without further assumptions : $R=\mathbb{Z}, A=\mathbb{Z/2Z}, B=\mathbb{Q}$, then $A\otimes_R B=0$ and thus $1\otimes 1=0$ but $1\neq 0$ in $B$.

Comment: @Roland I missed one further assumption. thank you

Comment: [nit] btw usually “In particular, (X).” means that (X) follows from previous assumptions

Comment: Still false (just swap $A$ and $B$ in my previous example).

Comment: @Roland Oh dear... Thank you. I will edit to put the exact situation I have.

Comment: Since $B$ is flat (as a localization), we have that $B=R\otimes_R B\to A\otimes_R B$ is into. Since the image of $x$ is $0$, it must be that $x$ is zero.